# Use a variable that could contain special characters into sed?

Tags: bash, sed, bash-scripting

I have a bash script that'll take any word passed to it as a parameter and then encrypt the word using an openssl command.  From there I want to take the returned string and use sed to write it into another file.  The encrypted value sometimes contains the "/" character (but not always) at which point sed fails to function.

Here's the gist of what the script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

fileDirectory"/etc/ci"
fileName="key.bin"

encryptedOSPFPW='echo $1 | openssl enc -a -A -aes-256-cbc -md sha256 -pass file:"$fileDirectory"/"$fileName"'

sed -i "s/OSPFPW/$encryptedOSPFPW/g" /etc/quagga/ospfd.conf

exit 0
```

How can I adjust the sed command so that it'll substitute whatever is returned into literally.  I know that if I replace the double-quotes with single-quotes, sed will take whatever's supplied to it literally, but that doesn't work when I'm using a variable.

Thanks

Comment: Use a different delimiter, instead of `/` use  an arbitrary string like a pipe `|` or a comma `,` or a `@` or ...

Comment: Ditto. `openssl enc -a` uses base64. This means there are many symbols that cannot appear in its output. Another issue may be with `echo $1 | …`. This fragment is poor code.

Comment: @Jetchisel, I can use a different delimeter?  I've never used anything besides /.  That's pretty cool.  I'll give that a try.

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski, In what manner would you suggest that I modify my openssl command to make it better?  Thanks

Comment: I guess these single-quotes after `encryptedOSPFPW=` should be backquotes. Use [`$( )`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5782/108618). Do not use `echo`, use [`printf`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618) or (in Bash) here string. And double-quote `$1`. Quotes outside and inside `$( )` do not mix, they are parsed separately. The code may be `encryptedOSPFPW="$(<<<"$1" openssl …)"`. The outer double-quotes are not really necessary *in this case*, but in general [double-quoting `$( )` is good](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).

Comment: @Jetchisel Could you post your response as an answer so that I can mark it accordingly?  Thanks.

Comment: @dutsnekcirf, It's I'll eave it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question was to use a different delimiter with the sed command.  I ended up using the following command:

```
sed -i "s|OSPFPW|$encryptedOSPFPW|g" /etc/quagga/ospfd.conf
```

Comment: You're the man!